# Whats the correct way to dispose table adapters and data sets?

Tags: c#, database, idisposable

I've been working on a project that uses table adapters and datasets to access an access database. I'm near completion and ran code analysis from visual studio and it came up with some errors about needing to implement IDisposable on specific classes that I use these methods. While I've looked at a few different things on this about having a dispose method or using a using block, I'm not really sure how to make this work. The dataset and table adapters are created as global variables to be used by the whole class, many classes will call on other classes which will also use different table adapters and datasets. I've tried creating a Dispose method, but I don't know when to call it and I am wondering if it is called at the wrong time will it crash my program. Here is a sample of one of the classes that I need to implement Idisposable :

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

 namespace recipeDataBase 
 {
     class NewRecipe : IDisposable
     {
         recipiesNewDataSet recipeDataSet = new recipiesNewDataSet();
         recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.RecipeTableAdapter recipeTableAdapter = new      recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.RecipeTableAdapter();
    recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.RecipeIngredientTableAdapter recipeIngredientTableAdapter = new recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.RecipeIngredientTableAdapter();
    recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.RatingTableAdapter ratingTableAdapter = new recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.RatingTableAdapter();
    recipeDataBase.recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.IngredientTableAdapter ingredientTableAdapter = new recipiesNewDataSetTableAdapters.IngredientTableAdapter();
    private RecipeInfo newRecipe;
    private RatingNum originalRatingNum;
    private RatingNum newRating;
    private RecipeInfo originalRecipe;
    private string[] ingredients;

    public NewRecipe(RecipeInfo incommingNewRecipe, RatingNum IncommingNewRating, string[] incommingIngredients)
    {
        newRecipe = incommingNewRecipe;
        newRating = IncommingNewRating;
        ingredients = incommingIngredients;
        CreateNewRecipe();
        UpdateNewRecipe();
    }
    public void CreateNewRecipe()
    {
        originalRatingNum = new RatingNum();
        originalRecipe = new RecipeInfo();
        originalRatingNum.cookingTime = 0;
        originalRatingNum.easeOfCooking = 0;
        originalRatingNum.familyRating = 0;
        originalRatingNum.healthRating = 0;
        originalRatingNum.userRating = 0;

        ratingTableAdapter.Fill(recipeDataSet.Rating);
        ratingTableAdapter.Insert(originalRatingNum.userRating, originalRatingNum.familyRating, originalRatingNum.healthRating, originalRatingNum.easeOfCooking, originalRatingNum.cookingTime);
        Query getNewRecipeNumbers = new Query();
        int newRatingNumber = getNewRecipeNumbers.newRatingNum();



        originalRatingNum.ratingNum = newRatingNumber;
        newRating.ratingNum = newRatingNumber;
        newRecipe.ratingNum = newRatingNumber;
        originalRecipe.recipeName = "newRecipe";
        originalRecipe.nationality = "newRecipe";
        originalRecipe.recipeEvent = "newRecipe";
        originalRecipe.source = "newRecipe";
        originalRecipe.type = "newRecipe";
        originalRecipe.servings = "0";
        originalRecipe.ratingNum = newRatingNumber;


        recipeTableAdapter.Fill(recipeDataSet.Recipe);
        recipeTableAdapter.Insert(originalRecipe.recipeName, originalRecipe.nationality, originalRecipe.recipeEvent, originalRecipe.source, originalRecipe.type, originalRecipe.servings, originalRecipe.ratingNum); 
        int newRecipeNum = getNewRecipeNumbers.newRecipeNum();
        newRecipe.recipeNum = newRecipeNum;
        originalRecipe.recipeNum = newRecipeNum;
        recipeDataSet.AcceptChanges();
    }

    public void UpdateNewRecipe()
    {
        UpdateRatingNum updateRatingNum = new UpdateRatingNum(originalRatingNum, newRating);
        UpdateRecipe updateRecipe = new UpdateRecipe(newRecipe, originalRecipe);

        UpdateIngredients updateIngredients = new UpdateIngredients(ingredients);
        UpdateRecipeIngredient updateRecpeIngredients = new UpdateRecipeIngredient(ingredients, newRecipe.recipeNum);
        recipeDataSet.AcceptChanges();

    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        ratingTableAdapter.Dispose();
        recipeTableAdapter.Dispose();
        recipeTableAdapter.Dispose();
        ingredientTableAdapter.Dispose();
        recipeDataSet.Dispose();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

As you can see I did implement Idisposable and used the automatically created method to put all of the table adapters and dataset in there to be disposed, but how do I use it and where?

Thanks for the help

Craig

Comment: You may want to remove the NotImplementedException first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers the correct way to **usage** an object that implements `IDisposable` is withing a using block as follows:

```
using (var recipe = new NewRecipe())
{
    //put your code that uses recipe here
}
```

What I would like to point out though is the correct **implementation** of the IDisposable pattern. Note that there is a complete example on the [MSDN article for the IDisposable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

```
class Recipe : IDisposable
{
    bool isDisposed = false;
    TableAdapter myDisposableMember;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SupressFinalize(this);
    }

    public virtual Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (!isDisposed) //only clean up once
        {
            //clean up unmanaged resource here
            //in this case we don't have any

            //clean up managed resources (IE those that implemetn IDisposable only if
            //Dispose() was called (not the case when invoked during finalisation)
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                if(myDisposableMember == null)
                {
                    myDisposableMember.Dispose()
                    myDisposablemember = null;
                }
            }

            //mark this instance as cleaned up
            isDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    //if our class has any unmanaged resources you implement a destructor to guarantee
    //that they're freed. We don't have any here so we don't implement it.
    //~Recipe()
    //{
    //    Dispose(false);
    //}
}
```

Also note that you should NEVER throw an exception during finalization (IE: `~Recipe()`). Consequently `Dispose(bool)` should NEVER throw an exception.

Comment: It is the right and complete pattern but here it is serious overkill.

Comment: @Henk Yes, in this scenario you could lose the `isDisposed` variable and merge the two `Dispose` methods because this class doesn't encapsulate any unmanaged resources. That being said if you're going to teach somebody how to do something you should give them the full picture. It is not unreasonable to assume that the OP will take the answers here and apply them to similar problems down the road from a broader scope. Not to mention the that other users are likely to stumble upon this thread that may need the full scope of this answer.

Comment: Ok, so I implemented Idisposible on all classes that needed it and I try to put a using statment such as using (var nr = new NewRecipe()) {newRecipe = new NewRecipe(newRecipeInfo, newRatingNum, ingredientList);} now I get a compiler error on the using line because this class doesn't contain a constructor that uses 0 arguments, which is true. Do I need to put a new constructor in this class as well?

Comment: Looks like you already found the answer but figured I would post the answer here anyways for future readers: `using (var nr = new NewRecipe(incommingNewRecipe, IncommingNewRating, incommingIngredients)) {}` where incommingNewRecipe, IncommingNewRating and incommingIngredients are the paramters to the appropriate NewRecipe constructor.

Comment: I got it now, I'm down to 8 warnings from over 20 something, now I've got some that have nothing to do with my data access

Answer (score 2):

The normal pattern:

```
using (var nr = new NewRecipe() )
{
   ...
}
```

But a few notes here:

- the IDisposable interfaces on DataSet and DataAdapter are dummies, you won't lose much when you skip them.
- Your class has a dual role of Repository and Domain object. Consider separating it into 2 classes.

Comment: and that would be place in the method that creates the NewRecipe object?

Comment: Not sure which method you mean, I see a constructor and a CreateNewRecipe. But the using should be outside this class.

Comment: I think the further I get into this project I realize that there's alot to learn i.e. Repository and Domain object. I took this project from one that had all of these methods in 5 winforms and tried to break it up into more reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of using is `using`. Just don't take it in your hands -

```
using(DataAdapter ratingTableAdapter = new DataAdapter())
{

}
```

*ratingTableAdapter* will get disposed once the code comes out of the using block.

Comment: so I put the using statment in the code that actually creates the newRecipe object and get rid of the public void Dispose() method in the NewRecipe class?  This is where I get lost.